# How can I use an SSL certificate with my Next JS deployment?

Tags: javascript, node.js, deployment, next.js, ssl-certificate

I have a Next.js deployment on an EC2 instance. I want to install an SSL certificate. The only way I can think of is to use a custom server config, but this seems to remove certain optimizations that I'd rather keep. Keep in mind I am starting the server using 'next start'.

The solutions I found online only apply to local deployments and they also involve using a custom server config.

Thanks

Comment: Based on existing answers it looks like you need to a) run the nextjs app on port 3000 (or some other port, just not 443) b) use a web server like apache or nginx to handle SSL c) proxy the requests to your nextjs server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

an option is to use `nginx` and host configs

https://medium.com/today-i-solved/how-to-deploy-next-js-on-aws-ec2-with-ssl-https-7980ec6fe8d3

Comment: how can we do it without using nginx ? Is it possible to configure ssl in nodejs where the application is deployed ?

Answer (score 7):

One of the quickest solutions is to:

1. Dockerize Next.js application
2. Set up a Docker Compose environment with two containers: the Next.js application itself and NGINX (the image is available on [DockerHub](https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx) to it's a matter of pulling it)
3. Configure NGINX as a reverse proxy that handles the SSL part

With this approach, the question becomes a duplicate of [this other SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74185594/8929855). Details and code examples (in particular for the third point) are available there.

Answer (score 0):

As of the latest version of Next.js, this is now supported through `next dev --experimental-https`.