# How to deploy a Next.js app on HTTPS (SSL connection) with Docker?

Tags: docker, nginx, ssl, next.js, https

I'm following the instructions on Next.js' documentation to start the server using Docker: https://nextjs.org/docs/deployment#docker-image

Loading the site with http works but https returns SSL protocol errors.

What I did in detail:

1. Configured NGINX and cerbot (note that the guide is for Ubuntu 20) https://certbot.eff.org/instructions?ws=nginx&os=ubuntufocal on my DigitalOcean Ubuntu 22.4 server
2. Copied `Dockerfile` and `.dockerignore` from the example project linked in the docs to my project: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-docker
3. Built and uploaded the image to the server.
4. Started the image on the server: `docker run -p 80:3000 -p 443:3000 my_image`

HTTP works perfectly (`https://mysite.mydomain`). With HTTPS I get errors, e.g. `ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR` on Chrome and `SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG` on Firefox.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you clarify how this is being run? Do you have a single DO droplet that you're running both nginx and your docker image on? If so, are you also running nginx as a docker image?

Comment: @DavidT Yes, I'm using a regular DO droplet. I installed Docker there manually (apt).  NGINX was installed via apt as well, it's not a Docker image.

Comment: Anyway, for now I gave up and migrated the app to Netlify. You can add a reply but I'll not be able to test it.

Comment: Probably the right call. Netlify and Vercel are great tools for Next.js apps. If anyone comes here trying to run it themselves using docker and SSL, I suspect the issue here had to do with colliding ports on port 443. It sounds like both nginx and the docker image were configured to listen on port 443 which would cause issues with routing on the DO droplet since they're on the same host machine.

Comment: @DavidT. Okay thanks for those infos!

Answer (score 12):

The following steps explain how to set up a multi-container Docker Compose environment where NGINX is used as a reverse proxy in front of the Next.js application to handle the SSL connection (and offer an HTTPS URI).

###### Step 1 - Dockerize Next.js application

Luckily, this is part of the [Next.js official docs themselves](https://nextjs.org/docs/deployment#docker-image). The key step is to copy [this Dockerfile](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-docker/Dockerfile) to the Next.js repo you are working on.

Gotchas:

- It's a good idea to copy [.dockerignore](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-docker/.dockerignore) as well
- Set `output: 'standalone'` in `next.config.js` (like [this](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-docker/next.config.js))
- We will place a reverse proxy in front of the Next.js app, so the port in the `Dockerfile` (3000 by default) is not what will be externally exposed; there's no need to expose that port publicly
- Make sure that the image builds: `docker build -t nextjs:latest -f Dockerfile .`

###### Step 2 - Set up a Docker Compose environment

The Docker Compose environment will have two running containers: the Next.js app and NGINX.

The NGINX image can be created by adding a second `Dockerfile`:

```
# nginx/Dockerfile

FROM nginx:1.23.3-alpine

COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
```

Build the image from the project root dir with `docker build -t nginx:latest -f nginx/Dockerfile nginx`.

Then, we can create a `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  nextjs:
    image: nextjs:latest
    container_name: nextjs
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    restart: always
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - /etc/ssl:/etc/nginx/ssl:ro
    restart: always
```

Gotchas:

- An empty `nginx.conf` can be added for now, it'll be configured in the next step
- Ports 80 (HTTP) and 443 (HTTPS) will be exposed pubicly, so they need to be open
- The SSL certificate and key are made available through a Docker volume. They are assumed to exist in the host machine under `/etc/ssl`. An alternative would be to pack them in the NGINX image (e.g. add `COPY my_ssl_cert.crt /etc/nginx/ssl/my_ssl_cert.crt` to the `Dockerfile`, idem for the key)

###### Step 3 - Configure NGINX as a reverse proxy

Example `nginx.conf`:

```
# nginx/nginx.conf

events {
}

http {
    upstream nextjs {
        server nextjs:3000;
    }
    server {
        # Redirect HTTP requests to HTTPS.
        listen 80;
        server_name localhost;
        root /srv/public;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

    server {
        listen 443 ssl;

        server_name localhost;
        root /srv/public;
        server_tokens off;

        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/my_ssl_cert.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/my_ssl_key.key;

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ @nextjs;
        }

        location @nextjs {
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Ssl on;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_pass http://nextjs;
            proxy_cookie_path / "/; HTTPOnly; Secure";
        }
    }
}
```

Gotchas:

- We can refer to the Next.js app by its default hostname `nextjs` because *by default Compose sets up a single network for your app* ([docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/))

###### Step 4 - Deploy

1. Build both Docker images
2. Ship both Docker images, the SSL files, and `docker-compose.yml` to the server
3. In the server, run `docker compose up`
4. If required, use `docker logs [container_name]` to debug any issues; `curl http://localhost:80` and `curl --insecure https://localhost:443` can also help

Answer (score 0):

This answer was really useful. For me on Ubuntu 20.4

```
docker build -t nextjs:latest -f Dockerfile
```

needs to be

```
docker build -t nextjs:latest -f Dockerfile .
```

(yes, the dot)

also for some reason docker can only work on directories that are two levels down from the base.. so for example /var/www but not /var/www/html

I have no idea why this isn't actually documented on the internet (at least not that I could find)

Comment: The original answer includes the final `.` in the `docker build [...]` command